# Why is my PATCH request's response empty ? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, patch

I have an app runs Rails in backend, Javascript frontend. My controllers, routes and CORS is fine. My Post and Get requests are working fine. However when I make a patch request, it successfully does patching but as `response.text()`, I get empty  string. So when I use `response.json()`, it gives me `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at game.js:25 error.` I need to know the source of the problem.

```js
static patchGame() {
        const numberOfClicks = parseInt(document.getElementById('click-number').textContent, 10)
        const score = parseInt(document.getElementById('score').textContent,10)
        const gameID = document.getElementById('gameID').value
        const gameObj = {game: {click_number: numberOfClicks, score: score}}
        const options = {
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                      "Accept": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify(gameObj)
        }
            fetch(`http://localhost:3000/games/${gameID}`, options).then(resp => {debugger}).then(game => { debugger }) // NEVER HITS last debugger    
    }
```

These are the resp debugger values I get,

```js
>resp

<-Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/games/28", redirected: false, status: 204, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 204
statusText: "No Content"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3000/games/28"
__proto__: Response



>resp.text()

<-Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "pending"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined


>resp.json()

<-Promise {<rejected>: TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read
    at eval (eval at <a…}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read at eval (eval at <anonymous> (file:///Users/muratogulcansahin/Desktop/DanceMemory/frontend/game.js:1:1), <anonymous>:1:6) at file:///Users/muratogulcansahin/Desktop/DanceMemory/frontend/game.js:24:84
message: "Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read"
stack: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (file:///Users/muratogulcansahin/Desktop/DanceMemory/frontend/game.js:1:1), <anonymous>:1:6)\n    at file:///Users/muratogulcansahin/Desktop/DanceMemory/frontend/game.js:24:84"
__proto__: Error



>resp.body

<-ReadableStream {locked: true}
locked: true
__proto__: ReadableStream
```

Comment: Can you show what the response body is exactly?

Comment: Try to print out the response object to console to see what we are working with. `.then(resp => console.log(resp)`

Comment: Hey – can you show the corresponding controller action for this route?(As well as any logic related to returning the data object you may have in concerns or libs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: I had mis-read the question, and only went on debugger values instead of reading the question fully. This is the correct answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67453072/1710359. I will leave this answer as-is in case someone else has this issue too.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

The code that fails is *not* in the code that was provided.

This is caused by using `.json()` multiple times, and is (I assume) located within that second `.then()` call.

Please revise your code and make sure you only call `.json()` *one* time per request, as `.json()` consumes the resulting body.

You are able to monitor if the body has been consumed by using the `.bodyUsed` variable, which is available in any `fetch` response.

This is an explanation based on your own debugger logs:

```js
>resp 

<-Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/games/28", redirected: 
// prints your server's response data (resp.bodyUsed is now *false*)


>resp.text()

<-Promise {<pending>}
// prints your server's response data as *text*, and *consumes* the body (resp.bodyUsed is now *true*)


>resp.json()

<-Promise {<rejected>: TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body
// fails to print your server's response data, because you have *already* consumed the body by using `.text()`
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You were right. The missing part was on my GamesController #update method ```render json: game``` was missing which is crucial for this event.

Comment: @murat-ogulcan-sahin glad that my answer pointed you in the right direction. I think you should mark Damilare's question as the answer, though, as it much better answers the initial question than my answer  does.

Answer (score 3):

it looks like there is a `204` response, which is what I'd expect from a successful `PATCH`, meaning no content is being returned from the server. That would certainly explain the issues you are having with this.

Basically, I won't expect to be able to call `.text()` or more specifically `.json()` on the absent content.

Ideally, `PUT` and `PATCH` requests are not expected to return data. `200`s are acceptable but `204`s are the most appropriate in my honest opinion

Comment: you can see that the error message specifies `body stream already read`, which indicates that he's using `.json()` or `.text()` multiple times

Comment: You may be right in this case, if the code that is failing is not what was posted here. However, I lean towards thinking that the real issue stems from the fact that there is no JSON response to access in the first place

Comment: @gear4 It says 'already read' because the response body is empty so there is nothing to convert to javascript object.

Comment: that is *not* the issue in this code. If there was *no* content, then the JSON error would be `"Unexpected end of JSON input"`

Here is a piece of could that *should* show both error messages (it's a DELETE on an endpoint that returns a 204 with no content: `fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2", { method: "DELETE" }).then(data => {data.json(); data.json()})`

Comment: Looking at the response, it's a `204` no? Could be wrong, I don't know what the corresponding controller action looks like, but it looks like a case of no content

Comment: @damilare-olusakin @murat-ogulcan-sahin apologies, I had mis-read the question. this is the correctly answer. however, you can call `.text()` on absent content; it would just return `undefined`

Comment: No worries! You can call `.text` yes, but it will return a pending promise

Comment: @damilare-olusakin you can call `.json` too, and it will also resolve with a pending promise :p you just have to handle the result of that promise